# How to clear pre tag in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im using PRE tag of HTML and I need on click to clear the content of it,
I've tried the following without success.

```
$('#display').clear;
$('#display').val("");
```

In the index html I use it like this

```
<pre id="display"></pre>
```

Comment: tried `.html("")` or `.text("")`

Comment: `.empty()` too is there.....:)

Comment: If you are using  any library/framework methods do try to see their documention first. It's easy to know what to expect from specific method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `$('selector').val('')` and it is for input boxes, and won't work here!

I suggest you to use one of the bellow ways:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#delete-1").click(function(){
  $('#display1').html('');
});

$("#delete-2").click(function(){
  document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML ="";
});


$("#delete-3").click(function(){
  $('#display3').empty();
});

  
$("#delete-4").click(function(){
  $('#display4').text('');
});

  
  
 



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="display1">
  
  Here is pre content
</pre>

<br/>
<pre id="display2">
  
  Here is pre content
</pre>

<br/>
<pre id="display3">
  
  Here is pre content
</pre>
<br/>
<pre id="display4">
  
  Here is pre content
</pre>

<br/>
<a id="delete-1" href="#">Delete #1</a>
<a id="delete-2" href="#">Delete #2</a>
<a id="delete-3" href="#">Delete #3</a>
<a id="delete-4" href="#">Delete #4</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `html("")` to clear content

```
 $('#display').html("");
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jquery then use:

```
<script>
$( "#display" ).empty();
</script>
```

Make sure you are loading jquery.

Answer (score 2):

Try using simple javascript

```
document.getElementById('display').innerHTML ="";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#display').html("");
```

Here is the working fiddle example.
https://fiddle.jshell.net/75fLkhmz/

Answer (score 0):

this clear the data between the tag

```
$('#display').text('');
```